# HTML5 Video not showing up in Chrome before scroll

Tags: html, google-chrome, video, html5-video

I have a problem with HTML5 Video and Google Chrome.

When I load my page. I can't see the video. No poster image, no video frame.
The video element does exist.

Now if I scroll a little bit the video is showing up and plays.
Its like "Please Scroll to Render and Play the Video"..

This is my code:

```
<video id="videocontainer" loop autoplay preload="auto" poster="http://homepage.de/video/poster.jpg">
    <source src="http://homepage.de/video/BigWeb.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    <source src="http://homepage.de/video/BigWeb.webm" type="video/webm" />
    <source src="http://homepage.de/video/BigWeb.ogv" type="video/ogg" />
    <object id="videocontainer-object">
        <param name="movie" value="http://fpdownload.adobe.com/strobe/FlashMediaPlayback.swf"></param>
        <param name="flashvars" value="http://homepage.de/video/BigWeb.mp4&playButtonOverlay=false&loop=true&autoPlay=true&controlBarMode=none"></param>
        <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param>
        <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param>
        <embed id="videocontainer-embed" src="http://fpdownload.adobe.com/strobe/FlashMediaPlayback.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="1280" height="720" flashvars="src=http://homepage.de/video/BigWeb.mp4&controlBarMode=none&playButtonOverlay=false&loop=true&autoPlay=true"></embed>
    </object>
</video>
```

**Edit: I made something up on fiddle. http://jsbin.com/japewido/1/watch 
When i use "controls" everything is ok on Google Chrome. Whithout controls. The Video is not starting. No Poster Image. Just a blank Video Element.**

**Edit 2nd: After Looking Up what the current vesion of google chrome is (34) and i saw that i was using google chrome 26 (the auto updater didnt work). I Installed the current version and it works now... (i want my time back^^)**

Comment: Can you reproduce your problem in a minimal [fiddle](http://jsbin.com) ?

Comment: @dystroy http://jsbin.com/japewido/1/watch

Comment: If you wait long enough, you don't have to scroll. Looks like the browser takes the scroll as a hint it should start the video immediately and maybe less buffer (it's immediate for me if the video is in cache). I don't know if it qualifies as a bug or not.

Comment: @dystroy Mhh waitig doesnt work for me. Its not showing up. I have to interact with the Page. Scrolling or Mouse Over a Link.

Comment: @dystroy I Removed the poster image and this seems to help. The Video ist starting right away?

Comment: Yes it does. I hadn't noticed the poster. It probably confirms the browser is being smart in a way that you don't like. Maybe you should confirm that and post an answer.

Comment: Starts immediately for me in Chrome 34 ?

Comment: A side note - It is good idea to always include `width` and `height` attributes of the video tag. If `height` and `width` are set, the space required for the video is reserved when the page is loaded. 

However, without these attributes, the browser does not know the size of the video, and cannot reserve the appropriate space to it. The effect will be that the page layout will change during loading (while the video loads).

Comment: @adeneo i updated chrome after recognizing that the google chrome updater didnt work. (i used 26...) now with version 34 ist work.

Comment: @bodi0 i set the width and height via css.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script> 
var myVideo=document.getElementById("videocontainer"); 
myVideo.load();
</script>
```

try this

Comment: I tried this before, The "Problem" was a very old chrome version (26). With the latest version everything is ok.